# Solve $T(n) = T(n-1)+\log^2(n)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I was trying to solve

> $T(n) = T(n-1)+\log^2(n)$

using *substitution method* and *variables substitution* but I can't find the correct answer.

**My attempt**:

Let $m = \log(n)$

then $T(2^m) = T(2^m-1)+m^2$

next, we assume that $S(m) = T(2^m)$

so $S(m) = S(m-1)+m^2$ but here I'm stuck with this passage and I can't continue. Am i doing something wrong? Any tips?

Comment: what's $S(m)$ in terms of $S(m-2)?$ then continue to $S(1).$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Can I consider $S(m) = S(m-i)$ where $i$ goes from $1$ to $m$?

Comment: $S(m)=S(m-2)+(m^2+(m-1)^2),$ right? then $S(m)=S(1)+(m^2+(m-1)^2+\cdots+2^2).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T(n)-T(n-1)=\log^2(n)$, then $(T(n)-T(n-1))+(T(n-1)-T(n-2))+\ldots+(T(2)-T(1))=\log^2(n)+\ldots+\log^2(2)$, so $T(n)-T(1)=\log^2(n)+\ldots+\log^2(2)$,
$$T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{k=2}^n\log^2(k)$$.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging gives 
$$T(n)-T(n-1)=\log^2(n)$$
which is then convenient for telescoping, i.e. 
$$\begin{align}
&T(n)&-T(n-1)&=\log^2(n)\\
&T(n-1)&-T(n-2)&=\log^2(n-1)\\
&T(n-2)&-T(n-3)&=\log^2(n-2)\\
&\cdots  \\
&T(3)&-T(2)&=\log^2(3)\\
&T(2)&-T(1)&=\log^2(2)\\
\end{align}$$

Summing gives

$$T(n)-T(1)=\sum_{r=2}^{n}\log^2 r\\
T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{r=2}^{n}\log^2 r$$